# Using Cursors to return a specified number of results

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a cursor in my SQL 2008R2 database. This cursor takes a list of data, parses each row the data, and then runs the parsed data row through a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE ExecsDataCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT TOP (@GuessListSize)
        ExecutiveId,
        CompanyExecutiveId,
        Email,
        CompanyId,
        @EmailPatternID EmailPatternID,
        ExecNameForSorting
    FROM
        CompanyExecutive
    WHERE
        CurrentlyWithCompany = 1
        AND
        Email IS NULL
        AND
        CompanyExecutiveId NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT CompanyExecutiveId 
            FROM ExecsData_ExecutiveCandidates
            WHERE EmailPatternID = @EmailPatternID
        )
    ORDER BY
        CompanyExecutiveId

    OPEN ExecsDataCursor

    DECLARE
        @ExecutiveId INT,
        @CompanyExecutiveId INT,
        @Email NVARCHAR(255),
        @CompanyId INT,
        @EmailPatternID_ForCursor TINYINT,
        @ExecName NVARCHAR(255)

    FETCH NEXT FROM ExecsDataCursor
    INTO 
        @ExecutiveId ,
        @CompanyExecutiveId ,
        @Email ,
        @CompanyId ,
        @EmailPatternID_ForCursor,
        @ExecName

    DECLARE 
        @FirstName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
        @MiddleName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
        @LastName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
        @ExampleEmail NVARCHAR(255),
        @Domain NVARCHAR(50) = ''

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ')) = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FirstName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 1
        END

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ')) = 2
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FirstName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 1
            SELECT @LastName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 2
        END

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ')) >= 3
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FirstName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 1
            SELECT @MiddleName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 2
            SELECT @LastName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' '))
        END

        SELECT @ExampleEmail = MAX(Email) FROM CompanyExecutive WHERE Email IS NOT NULL AND CompanyId = @CompanyId
        SELECT @Domain = SUBSTRING(@ExampleEmail, CHARINDEX('@', @ExampleEmail), LEN(@ExampleEmail))            

        IF @EmailPatternID = 1 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fnamelname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 2 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fnamedotlname@domain_DataMe @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 3 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitiallname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 4 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitialdotlname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 5 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitial_lname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 6 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fname_lname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 7 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fnamelinitial@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 8 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lnamefinitial@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 9 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 10 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lname_fname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 11 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 12 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitiallinitial@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END
        IF @EmailPatternID = 13 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lnamedotfname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH  END

            FETCH NEXT FROM ExecsDataCursor
                INTO 
                    @ExecutiveId ,
                    @CompanyExecutiveId ,
                    @Email ,
                    @CompanyId ,
                    @EmailPatternID_ForCursor,
                    @ExecName
    END
    CLOSE ExecsDataCursor
    DEALLOCATE ExecsDataCursor
```

This works very well, at least by my expectations. The cursor processes 8000 rows in about 19 seconds. The 8000 rows are specified by user input, which feeds to the @GuessListSize parameter. However, the parsed data is not always processed correctly, which is to be expected. Hence, the try-catch code. We don't really need the cursor to do anything with the failed stored procedure executions. We started tracking them in a separate table so we can figure out how to better process these data points in the future.

The issue with this is that the cursor now will not return a full list. We are hoping for a list of a size specified by the user. So the cursor pulls the list of the specified size, as it should, but some of those entries may not be properly processed by the stored procedures, returning a list less than the specified size.

So the next thing I tried was a WHILE loop. Now, the WHILE loop worked fine. It returned all of the rows the user requested. However, it took nearly 30 minutes to run through the same size of data set. This is obviously unacceptable.

```
DECLARE
        @ExecutiveId INT,
        @CompanyExecutiveId INT,
        @Email NVARCHAR(255),
        @CompanyId INT,
        @EmailPatternID_ForCursor TINYINT,
        @ExecName NVARCHAR(255) 


    DECLARE 
        @FirstName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
        @MiddleName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
        @LastName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
        @ExampleEmail NVARCHAR(255),
        @Domain NVARCHAR(50) = '',
        @Counter SMALLINT = 0

    --WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    WHILE @Counter < @GuessListSize
    BEGIN

        SELECT @CompanyExecutiveId = 
            MIN(CompanyExecutiveID) 
        FROM CompanyExecutive 
        WHERE CurrentlyWithCompany = 1 AND Email IS NULL 
            AND 
            CompanyExecutiveId NOT IN 
            (SELECT CompanyExecutiveId FROM ExecsData_ExecutiveCandidates WHERE EmailPatternID = @EmailPatternID)
            AND
            CompanyExecutiveID NOT IN
            (SELECT CompanyExecutiveId FROM ExecsData_Errors)

        SELECT
            @ExecutiveId = ExecutiveId,
            @Email = Email,
            @CompanyId = CompanyId,
            @EmailPatternID_ForCursor = @EmailPatternID,
            @ExecName = ExecNameForSorting
        FROM 
            CompanyExecutive
        WHERE
            CompanyExecutiveId = @CompanyExecutiveId

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ')) = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FirstName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 1
        END

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ')) = 2
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FirstName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 1
            SELECT @LastName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 2
        END

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ')) >= 3
        BEGIN
            SELECT @FirstName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 1
            SELECT @MiddleName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = 2
            SELECT @LastName = Data FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' ') WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dbo.splitString(@ExecName,' '))
        END

        SELECT @ExampleEmail = MAX(Email) FROM CompanyExecutive WHERE Email IS NOT NULL AND CompanyId = @CompanyId
        SELECT @Domain = SUBSTRING(@ExampleEmail, CHARINDEX('@', @ExampleEmail), LEN(@ExampleEmail))

    IF @EmailPatternID = 1 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fnamelname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 2 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fnamedotlname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 3 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitiallname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 4 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitialdotlname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 5 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitial_lname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 6 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fname_lname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 7 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fnamelinitial@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 8 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lnamefinitial@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 9 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_fname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 10 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lname_fname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 11 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 12 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_finitiallinitial@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END
    IF @EmailPatternID = 13 BEGIN BEGIN TRY EXEC ExecsData_Guess_lnamedotfname@domain_DataME @ExecutiveID ,@CompanyExecutiveID ,@FirstName,@MiddleName ,@LastName ,@Domain ,@CompanyID; SET @Counter = @Counter + 1; END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO ExecsData_Errors (CompanyExecutiveID,EmailPatternID) VALUES (@CompanyExecutiveId,@EmailPatternID) END CATCH  END

    END
```

Because the Cursor is designed to chew through a pre-defined list of data, I'm not sure how to make said cursor "dynamic" and return the user-specified number of results regardless of errors. The WHILE loop has the "counter" only increase if the SP executes without hitting the CATCH block, but I don't know how to integrate that into the Cursor, or if I even can.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

(As requested, the INSERT SQL SPs)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExecsData_Guess_fname@domain_DataMe] 
( 
    @ExecutiveID int,
    @CompanyExecutiveID int,
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @MiddleName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @DomainName nvarchar(255),
    @CompanyID int
) 
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED 
DECLARE @GUESS nvarchar(255)

DECLARE @FirstInitial nvarchar(1)
DECLARE @MiddleInitial nvarchar(1)
DECLARE @LastInitial nvarchar(1)

set @FirstInitial = SUBSTRING(@FirstName, 1, 1) 
set @MiddleInitial = SUBSTRING(@MiddleName, 1, 1) 
set @LastInitial = SUBSTRING(@LastName, 1, 1) 

--*****Example****** 
--FirstName = Andy, 
--Middle Name = Xanadu,  
--Last Name = Farag, 
--Domain = @umphreys.com
--******************

--ex. andy@umphreys.com
set @GUESS = LTRIM(@FirstName)+ @DomainName
EXEC ExecsData_InsertEmailGuessByExec_DataMe
        @ExecutiveID,
        @CompanyExecutiveID,
        @GUESS,
        @CompanyID,
        9


RETURN (@@ERROR) 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExecsData_InsertEmailGuessByExec_DataMe]
( 
    @ExecutiveID int,
    @CompanyExecutiveID int, 
    @EmailAddress nvarchar(50),
    @CompanyID int,
    @EmailPatternID tinyint
)
AS

BEGIN
    INSERT ExecsData_ExecutiveCandidates
    (
        ExecutiveID,
        CompanyExecutiveID,
        EmailAddress,
        CompanyID,
        EmailPatternID,
        GuessTimestamp
    )

    VALUES
    ( 
        @ExecutiveID,
        @CompanyExecutiveID, 
        @EmailAddress,
        @CompanyID,
        @EmailPatternID,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )
END
```

Per RBarryYoung's suggestion, I opted to look at the actual SP inserting process a bit. One of the problems I found was that many of our Execs were not pulling a domain to concatenate into an email address. Expanding the areas where the script could look for domain information has improved the process to near-user-specified completion. While it's still not perfect, it's a step in the right direction.

As for finding ways to dynamically force a cursor to pull a specific number of rows, I'm thinking I might nest this particular SP in a second SP that uses the WHILE loop. So basically, while the list size is less than the user-specified list size, it will re-execute the insertion SP. That might work. If it works, I'll re-edit and post this as the solution.

Comment: What's the code in the `TowerData_guess_*` procedures?

Comment: It's a very basic INSERT statement that uses the parsed values supplied as part of the INSERT. We don't expect 100% successful inserts. Hence the reason for the Cursor to keep firing until it hits the user-specified number of results.

Comment: Then, frankly I'm surprised that 19 seconds is considered acceptable.  Anything more than a fraction of a second to insert 8000 rows would be considered very slow in most environments.  If you post the proc's `INSERT` code and explain why you expect it to fail sometimes, I am sure that we can get it to perform better.

Comment: While I appreciate the offers to optimize the SPs, the concern is trying to find a way to hybridize the Cursor and WHILE loop. I'm sure there are ways we can improve the actual insert, but having the user-specified data set be complete is the top priority. Simply put, if the user expects 2000 rows inserted, the WHILE loop ensures those 2000 rows are inserted. The Cursor merely starts with 2000 rows and then doesn't complete the rows that hit the CATCH block. I want the relatively improved speed of the cursor with the completeness of the WHILE loop.

Comment: I was talking about addressing both at the same time. Simply put, from a database perspective the best way to address this is to figure out *ahead of time* which rows will not be insertable and then filter them out before-hand. Using trial-and-error to insert-and-count is a relationally broken approach. But to fix it we would need to know what's going on in those procs and why some of the inserts fail.

Comment: The idea is that we're parsing people's names in an effort to create their email contact information. We take the parsed names and attempt to apply them to a series of patterns. Again, very simple stuff. But sometimes the names don't parse correctly, so the parameters break the concatenation. I'll update the original post.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, but I don't see any obvious reasons why the EXECs or INSERTs should fail.  What are the errors thrown when a row fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the last paragraph of the post, I ended up using nested SPs. The outermost SP runs a WHILE loop that keeps track of however many execs were requested. It then runs the generation SP with the specified number of execs. If the returned number is less than the requested number, it remains in the WHILE loop.

The errors in the generation SP are being logged to be reviewed by our data team.